# in mysql posting symbols "Ã,Õ ..." in mysql "&Atilde; &Otilde;"

Tags: mysql

how can fix this error   ???

```
mysql_query("
    update sondaje set  
    `oponent1`='$get[oponent1]', 
    `oponent2`='$get[oponent2]', 
    `intrebare`='$get[intrebare]', 
    `votes1`='$get[votes1]', 
    `votes2`='$get[votes2]', 
    `email`='$get[email]',
    `img1`='$get[img1]',
    `id`='$get[ids]',
    `date`='$get[date]',
    `img2`='$get[img2]'
    where `id`='$get[id]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

in mysql posting symbols "Ã,Õ ..."

Comment: Please learn something about “SQL Injection”.

Comment: What character set are you using in MySQL? (I can guess what problem you're having, but try not to make your question so brief next time. What are the values in that array, for example?)

Comment: foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
     $get[$key] = filter($value);
    }

useing utf8 i think pronblem this code